# How can I get name of interface from abstract class in PHP

Tags: php, function, oop, interface, abstract-class

It is possible in php to get an interface name without creating a new object?? For example:

```
interface my_interface{}

abstract class foo implements my_interface{

      public static function get_interface(){
             // here return name of interface
      }

}

class bar extends foo{}

echo bar::get_interface();
```

Expected Output :

```
 my_interface
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$r = new ReflectionClass(get_class()); // or get_called_class
foreach ($r->getInterfaceNames() as $name) {
    echo $name;
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getinterfacenames.php

Comment: thank you, i thought the reflection class need new instance of object. Anyway thank for answer

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the [`Reflection`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getinterfacenames.php) Class

```
$rc1 = new ReflectionClass("foo");
echo $rc1->getInterfaceNames()[0];
```

### The code..

```
<?php
interface my_interface{}

abstract class foo implements my_interface{

    public static function get_interface(){
        // here return name of interface
    }

}

$rc1 = new ReflectionClass("foo");
echo $rc1->getInterfaceNames()[0];
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
my_interface
```